# Jpa + Spring Data : cascading of a collection with compound key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm currently working on a small shop application for my School.

I have 2 objects I want to save :

Order.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class Order {
    private Integer id;
    private Date orderDate;
    private MailingAddress mailingAddress;
    private User user;
    private Collection<OrderLine> orderLines;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ORDER_DATE")
    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SHIPPING_ADR_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    public MailingAddress getMailingAddress() {
        return mailingAddress;
    }

    public void setMailingAddress(MailingAddress mailingAddressByShippingAdrId) {
        this.mailingAddress = mailingAddressByShippingAdrId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "LOGIN")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User userByUserId) {
        this.user = userByUserId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Collection<OrderLine> getOrderLines() {
        return orderLines;
    }

    public void setOrderLines(Collection<OrderLine> orderLinesesById) {
        this.orderLines = orderLinesesById;
    }
}
```

OrderLine.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_LINES", schema = "")
@IdClass(OrderLinesPK.class)
public class OrderLine {
    private int quantity;
    private Integer orderId;
    private String bookId;
    private Book book;
    private Order order;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "QUANTITY")
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORDERS_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Integer getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(Integer ordersId) {
        this.orderId = ordersId;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "BOOKS_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public String getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }

    public void setBookId(String booksId) {
        this.bookId = booksId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOKS_ID", referencedColumnName = "ISBN13", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(Book booksByBookId) {
        this.book = booksByBookId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDERS_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order ordersByOrderId) {
        this.order = ordersByOrderId;
    }
}
```

OrderLinesPK.java

```
public class OrderLinesPK implements Serializable {
    private int ordersId;
    private String booksId;

    @Column(name = "ORDERS_ID")
    @Id
    public int getOrderId() {
        return ordersId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(int ordersId) {
        this.ordersId = ordersId;
    }

    @Column(name = "BOOKS_ID")
    @Id
    public String getBookId() {
        return booksId;
    }

    public void setBookId(String booksId) {
        this.booksId = booksId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        OrderLinesPK that = (OrderLinesPK) o;

        if (ordersId != that.ordersId) return false;
        if (booksId != null ? !booksId.equals(that.booksId) : that.booksId != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = ordersId;
        result = 31 * result + (booksId != null ? booksId.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

An order contains a collection of order lines.
I'm trying to save the order + the order lines in one call to OrderRepository.
But when I do that, I get the error

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of edu.flst.bookstore.domaine.bo.OrderLinesPK.orderId
```

which is pretty logic (I know the Id of the order is unknow at this stage, because the primary key of order is auto-incremented (I use MySQL)).

I don't know how to make this work with **one call** to orderService (without saving orderLines with orderLinesRepository first). Is it even possible ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

An Order can contain many Books and a Book can appear in many Order(s). So the many-to-many relation is your OrderLine object essentially. I would set an id (autogenerated) and two many-to-one relations in OrderLine. Then you discard the OrderLinesPK class, you save the Order, Book and OrderLine objects in this order in the same transaction.In this way, your model is simpler and you only need to save an extra id (with no physical meaning) in the database (the id of the OrderLine object)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the db was part of the exercise, and I can't change it. Thus, I can't add an auto generated id for orderLine.